# C# How to compare 2 numbers that were pulled from a string

Tags: c#, string, linq, compare

I have to write a program that will intake a series of natural numbers separated by a comma like so [13,2,44,56,78,3,354] and pull a substring that has elements which are not smaller than the element before so for the example its [2,44,56,78]. If there are multiple such substrings to display the longer one. So far I have this.

```
using System;
using static System.Console;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {

    string s1 = ReadLine();

    string[] numbers = Regex.Split(s1, @"\D+");
    foreach (string value in numbers)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        {
            int i = int.Parse(value);
            int highest = 
        }
    } WriteLine(s1);

    Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Now I have to compare the numbers if the next one is smaller or bigger than the next and I am in a bind here. Any ideas?

Comment: greater then >, less then <.

Comment: You should use a `for` loop, not a `foreach`, and iterate to one less than the size of the collection so you can do `if (numbers[i] < numbers[i+1])`. Also your example looks wrong because you included 2 but it's smaller than 13.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you need something like shown below:

```
string numbers = "13,2,44,56,78,3,354,1,2,3,4,5,4";
var values = numbers.Split(',').Select(a => int.Parse(a)).ToArray();

var maxStart = values.Length > 0 ? values[0] : 0;
var maxLength = values.Length > 0 ? 1 : 0;
int currentStart = 0;
int currentLength = 1;

for (int i=0; i<values.Length; i++)
{
    if (i + 1 < values.Length && values[i + 1] >= values[i])
        currentLength++;
    else
    {
        if (currentLength > maxLength)
        {
            maxLength = currentLength;
            maxStart = currentStart;
        }
        currentStart = i + 1;
        currentLength = 1;
    }
}
Console.WriteLine("Start={0}, Length={1}, Sequence={2}", maxStart, maxLength,
    string.Join(",", values.Skip(maxStart).Take(maxLength)));
//Start=7, Length=5, Sequence=1,2,3,4,5
```

Comment: Exactly that. Thank you very much. I needed this for a interview but it showed me that basic training is way too little to even think about a job. I need to learn much much more.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I can't test this (or look up the correct calls) but hopefully you get the gist.  You read each number and see if its >= than the previousNumber.
If it is then you stash it in the list.  Once there is a number that is less than the previous number you print the sequence out and clear the list.

```
List<int> sequence = new List<int>(10);
int previousNumber = -1;
int currentNumber = -1;
foreach (string value in numbers)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
    {
        currentNumber = int.Parse(value);
        if (currentNumber >= previousNumber)
        {
            sequence[sequence.Length()] = currentNumber;
            previousNumber = currentNumber;
        }
        else
        {
            if (sequence.Length() > 1)
            { 
                // print sequence.
            }
            // Erase everything in the list.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Getting a error :
Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS1061 'List<int>' does not contain a definition for 'length' and no extension method 'length' accepting a first argument of type 'List<int>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) ConsoleApplication17 c:\users\mrbest\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ConsoleApplication17\ConsoleApplication17\Program.cs 27 Active

Comment: @KershelBest yes sorry about that, it's the disadvantage of programming in C++ for the last few months and trying to do it without reference.